# Django Forms does not submit radiobutton value and does not showing any output in terminal as well

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

This is HTML Code.

```
<form action = "." method = "post">
    <div class="form_data">

        {% csrf_token %}
         <br><br>

        {{form.myfield}}
<br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
</form>
```

This is forms.py code

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TestModel
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {'myfield': forms.RadioSelect()}
```

This is models.py code

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    git_Id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    git_Response = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_approved = models.IntegerField()
    MY_CHOICES = (
        ('opt0', 'Approved'),
        ('opt1', 'Not Approved'),
    )
    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=MY_CHOICES, default="N/A")
```

views.py code

```
def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("Form is Valid")
            selected = form.cleaned_data['myfield']
            print(selected)

            if selected == 'opt0':
                from config import request_id as r
                rq = r["request_id"]
                print(rq)
                s = sql()
                query = f"""update request_form_mymodel
                                       set is_approved=1
                                       where request_id = '{rq}' """
                print(query)
                s.update_query(query)
            else:
                pass

    else:
        form = TestForm()
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form})
```

I am not getting any output, if i try to submit after selecting radio button then it does not working and not printing any variables values in terminal as well and form is not submitted.
What I want - I want to getting form is submitted and if radiobutton is selected opt0 then s.update() is called.

Answer (score 0):

The form is not going to the `test` view as you specified `.` in `action` attribute, kindly remove `action` attribute, since Django always takes current page route, so it will automatically go to `test` view so:

```html
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form_data">

        {% csrf_token %}
         <br><br>

        {{form.myfield}}
<br><br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
</form>
```

Comment: No it does not work

Comment: @ShauryaRajput Does the form still not going to `test` view? What's the exact problem?

Comment: I use the same models and forms file for other (index) view.  but index view work for same approach but test view does not work.  MyModel for index and InputForm for index as well.

Comment: @ShauryaRajput Does it print `Form is valid` in terminal which you mentioned in print statement in view?